# Restore-SPSite : <nativehr> error and Content DB schema different

Tags: error, restore, patching, schema

We have 3 SP2013 on-premise standard farm in the company. One for development, one for test and then production. We deployed the 3 farms at the same time and all of them have patched to "June 2014 CU".

Recently we need to deploy a new site collection. After we complete, we will backup the new site collection using `Backup-SPSite` command. Then restore the same bak file to Test and then PROD environment. We can successfully restore to Test but not PROD. The error is

```
Restore-SPSite :<nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

(should I call it error?)

After research it make me believe PROD have different patch level. By checking via CA -> Manage Content Database, we found all the content DBs in **DEV** and **TEST** have same schema version
**current schema version: 15.0.4719.1000** while the **PROD** have **15.0.4617.1000**

I am sure no SharePoint update is made since June 2014. However I found some windows (for win 2008) security patches, some language pack update, and OWA update occur on DEV and TEST. I think they were deployed by WSUS recently.

Just in case, we install the same patches towards PROD but the schema version number didn't change in the Content Database detail.

Question:

1. Do I need to do something so make schema version number change? Like
   reboot? IS there a timer job update it?
2. Anything else I should
   check?
3. Is the `<nativehr>` error only caused by schema version
   different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patch levels are different. Install May 2015 CU or MS15-046 to the production server, depending on what was installed in dev/test.

Comment: Finally we found that install [MS15-047](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3054792) can update the schema towards 15.0.4719.1000. After patch we run Upgrade-SPContentDatabase and restore command works.